# Error: could not find function "sys.setenv"

Tags: rstudio, quarto

getting this errror "Error: could not find function "sys.setenv" when opening a quarto file in Rstudio. And when I click on the render button on quarto file, it throws some addtional error and the file doesnt render.

I have found a fix to it, when I run the following code in the console the issue gets fixed for a particular R session.
Sys.setenv(R_USER="my_user_name")
However, the problem is that I have to run it everytime I open a new Rstudio session. Is there is  a way that I save this code in the .Rprofile or somewhere such that Rstudio/quarto automatically detects it.

Comment: Case matters. The function is `Sys.setenv` with a capital S.

Comment: actually it still shows the error as "Error: could not find function "sys.setenv" but after setting the last line as "Sys.setenv(R_USER="my_user_name")" helped solved the problem, but I m still getting this error "Error: could not find function "sys.setenv" I believe is because in the same . Rprofile file I have set the python environment which starts with "sys.setenv". may be there is  better way to separate the two enviroment i.e. R and Python one in Rstudio.